# what is the difference between creating dockerfile for x86, armv7 32 and arm 64

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create dockerfile to install node and mongodb on top of alpine. How will the dockerfile differ for x86, armv7 32 and arm 64

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I did find the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `Dockerfile` starts with a

```
FROM <base_image>
```

declaration, so you will have to choose a base image that will be able to run on your system/architecture and build on top of it.

From [here](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64):

> ## Docker Official Images

> See [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/) for a good high-level overview of the program.

> ### Architectures other than amd64?

> Some images have been ported for other architectures, and many of these are officially supported (to various degrees).

> - Architectures officially supported by Docker, Inc. for running Docker: (see [download.docker.com](https://download.docker.com/linux/))
>   -   IBM z Systems (`s390x`): https://hub.docker.com/u/s390x/
>   -   ARMv7 32-bit (`arm32v7`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v7/
>   -   Windows x86-64 (`windows-amd64`): https://hub.docker.com/u/winamd64/
>   -   Linux x86-64 (`amd64`): https://hub.docker.com/u/amd64/

- Other architectures built by official images: (but *not* officially supported by Docker, Inc.)

  - IBM POWER8 (`ppc64le`): https://hub.docker.com/u/ppc64le/
  - x86/i686 (`i386`): https://hub.docker.com/u/i386/
  - ARMv8 64-bit (`arm64v8`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8/
  - ARMv6 32-bit (`arm32v6`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v6/ (Raspberry Pi 1, Raspberry Pi Zero)
  - ARMv5 32-bit (`arm32v5`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v5/

---

- You may also find other users/sources that use Docker Hub to upload their images. While doing some tests with [ffmpeg](https://hub.docker.com/r/tgogos/ffmpeg/) on a Raspberry Pi, I decided to trust the images provided by [resin.io](https://hub.docker.com/u/resin/) (**update:** now they are called [balena.io](https://balena.io) and here is their Docker hub: [hub.docker.com/u/balena](https://hub.docker.com/u/balena))
- If you are interested in learning how an image is created, you can check its `Dockerfile`. For example for Node.js on arm64v8 see the Dockerfiles [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/node/)